# Nginx list static files/directories as XML/Json

Tags: xml, json, nginx, webserver

I installed nginx with the intent of serving static files like photos and videos, being able to programmatically list the files served.

The problem is that this listing is done in a HTML page and for my application I needed to be able to process this listing (something like json or xml).

Is there anyway I can do this with nginx? (Or are there any other alternatives which solve my problem)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are some custom nginx modules for this.

Comment: Don't you know anything by memory? I searched in the 3rd party modules and didn't find any.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved the problem by adding a php script to the server to list the files.

Answer (score 8):

Since version 1.7.9 you can use `autoindex_format` set to `json` or `xml`, refer to [the docs here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format).

```
location / {
    ...
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format json;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The [ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html) Module (which produces a directory listing for requests ending with the slash character: `/`) included in NGINX *since version 1.7.9 (released 2014-12-23)* added an [`autoindex_format` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format) that **sets the format of a directory listing**:

> **Syntax:**   **`autoindex_format`**`html | xml | json | jsonp;`
>   **Default:**  `autoindex_format html`;
>   **Context:**  `http, server, location`

*Example* config to enable this feature (for JSON):

```
location / {
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_format json;
}
```

When the JSONP format is used then the name of a callback function is set with the `callback` request argument. **If that argument is missing or has an empty value, then the JSON format is returned**.

The JSON(P) response data structure (scheme) is defined as :

```js
callback(  // when format directive jsonp AND callback argument in request
  [ // a single one-dimensional Array (wrap) containing
    { // Objects representing directory entries, structured as:
      "name" :"*"                             //String
    , "type" :"directory"|"file"|"other"      //String, ONLY 1 OF THESE 3
    , "mtime":"Ddd, DD Mmm YYYY hh:mm:ss GMT" //String, RFC1123-date of HTTP-date defined by RFC2616
    , "size" :*   //Integer,  ONLY PRESENT IFF "type":"file" !!!!! 
    } /*
  , { // and repeating the above Object structure for each directory entry
    } */
  ]
); // end callbackFunction-call when jsonp
```

The `"name"`, `"mtime"`, `"type":"directory"` and `"type":"file"` should be pretty self-explanatory.
**Important** to note that the `"size"` field is ONLY present IFF `"type":"file"`, otherwise it is omitted entirely (see examples below) !!

`"type":"other"` deserves some further explanation:
Suppose you did something you'd *never do in production* and set `'root /;'` in the config on a linux system and subsequently index `/dev/` then you'd get directory-entries like:

```js
[
{ "name":"floppy", "type":"other", "mtime":"Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:16:56 GMT" },
{ "name":"loop0", "type":"other", "mtime":"Mon, 23 Oct 2017 15:16:56 GMT" }
// and so forth
]
```

There could be other examples for `"type":"other"`, if you know some, please leave a comment!

Special dot-current/dot-parent (`.`, `..`) **and** Dot-files/dot-folders (`.hidden`) are filtered (not present) in the response!
Interesting: special dot-current/dot-parent (`.`, `..`) can be added by your clientside code, just as the `ngx_http_autoindex_module` has hardcoded them into the default html-format response.

Here are two 'raw' response **examples** in their original 'formatting'.
**Note:** response line-endings are hardcoded as `CRLF`.

**JSON (and JSONP without callback):**

```js
[
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 }
]
```

**JSONP (with callback=foo):**
<sub>note: the leading block-comment is part of the JSONP response.</sub>

```js
/* callback */
foo([
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 }
]);
```

A painfully simple snippet consuming a JSONP callback and building a HTML table intended to unambiguously clarify the format:

```html
<script>
function foo(d){
  var i= 0
  ,   L= d.length
  ,   r= '<table border="1" cellpadding="4px" style="border-collapse:collapse"><thead style="border-bottom:4px solid black">\n'
       + '<tr><th style="width:80%">Name</th><th>Type</th><th>Last Modified</th><th>Size</th></tr>\n'
       + '</thead><tbody>\n'
  ;
  for(;i<L;++i)
    r+= '<tr><td>'  + d[i].name
      + '</td><td>' + d[i].type
      + '</td><td style="white-space: nowrap">' + d[i].mtime
      + '</td><td>' + (d[i].type==='file' ? d[i].size : '-')
      + '</td></tr>\n';

  r+='</tbody></table>';
  document.body.innerHTML=r;
}
</script>

<script> // JSONP        Use your own preferred JSON(P) fetchmethod
/* callback */
foo([
{ "name":"subdir", "type":"directory", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:16 GMT" },
{ "name":"image.jpg", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:16:39 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"test.html", "type":"file", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:09:18 GMT", "size":5 },
{ "name":"????", "type":"other", "mtime":"Tue, 24 Oct 2017 16:17:52 GMT" }
]);
</script>
```

That means that from here on you could filter and sort your results client-side. Also you could link up icons depending on file-type/extension etc.
Make it as wild as you'd like, good luck!

Some extra inspiration might be found in:

- [nginx-autoindex-js](https://github.com/kstep/nginx-autoindex-js) (a JavaScript frontend for Nginx JSON autoindex format)
- or [pretty-autoindex](https://github.com/spring-raining/pretty-autoindex)
  (currently has a ['bug'](https://github.com/spring-raining/pretty-autoindex/blob/master/src/pretty-autoindex.js#L160): it hides size when type=directory instead of correct behavior of hiding size when type!=file)

**Sources:**

- excellent help on the #nginx communitiy support IRC channel (on freenode) from user 'benbrown', thanks for the help in testing and pointing me to the relevant parts of the nginx source code
- http://lxr.nginx.org/ident?_i=ngx_http_autoindex_json
- http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/http/modules/ngx_http_autoindex_module.c#0693
- official unit tests: 
  https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx-tests/autoindex_format.t