# 403 Forbidden error when using nginx inside docker

Tags: docker, nginx, containers, nginx-config

I am trying to build a nginx webserver to share files among team members.

In 'ubuntu 16.04', I am running following command:

```
root@automation00-new:/home/test# docker run -d  -p 8081:80 -v /var/www/apj/:/usr/share/nginx/html --name test-nginx  nginx:latest
```

As shown below docker is able to mount the files successfully.

```
root@automation00-new:/home/test# docker exec ec795af0f1f2 ls /usr/share/nginx/html
Builds
Logs_for_perf_Testing
json.txt
ravi
root@automation00-new:/home/test#
```

But when I try to access webserver using browser "http://1.1.1.1/8081" I am seeing '403 forbidden' error.

But if I try 'http://1.1.1.1/8081/json.txt', I am able to view the 'json.txt' contents on browser.

I want to browse all the directories and files inside.

Any idea on how to fix this issue please?

Comment: You need to add `autoindex on;` directive to your nginx config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please give us more context in terms of your nginx configuration.
Are you using the default nginx.conf or do you have done modifications?

The solution should be [to add all relevant files to the nginx index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387118/nginx-list-static-files-directories-as-xml-json)

Details also here, you will need to modify your nginx.conf:
[autoindex needs to be turned on for the location /](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html#autoindex_format)